# Verifying my e-commerce business Facebook Page

Tags: facebook

How do I verify my business page if I am e-commerce business with no physical location to the public and don't use a telephone number? I just sell and deal online.

Answer (score 1):

From [Facebook Help Center](https://www.facebook.com/help/1288173394636262):

> Requesting a blue verification badge isn't available right now.

But you can [request a gray verification badge](https://www.facebook.com/help/100168986860974):

> To be eligible for a gray verification badge, you must be an admin of your business Page and your Page must:
>
> - Be [published](https://www.facebook.com/help/184605634921611?helpref=faq_content)
> - Have a [profile picture](https://www.facebook.com/help/284445998278828?helpref=faq_content) and [cover photo](https://www.facebook.com/help/333543230019115?helpref=faq_content)
> - Have posts
>
> To verify your Page:
>
> 1. Click **Settings** at the top of your Page.
> 2. From **General**, click **Page Verification**.
> 3. Click **Verify this Page**.
> 4. Enter a publicly listed phone number for your business, your country and language.
> 5. Click Call Me Now to allow Facebook to call you with a verification code.
> 6. Enter the 4-digit verification code and click Continue.

As you don't have phone number you can use business document to verify you page.

> If you prefer to verify your Page with a business document (example: phone bill), follow the steps above and click Verify this Page with documents instead at the bottom left of the window that appears, then upload a picture of an official document showing your business's name and address. We'll only use this information to verify your Page.

One Facebook receive your verification code or business document, they will review your info to confirm that it matches public records and send you a notification or email about your verification status within a few days.